# How to add Ripple effect in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I would like to add this nice effect to my  RecyclerView items but I don't know where to start. Does anyone know of a good and simple tutorial on this topic?

[image]

Comment: If you are designing your app with material-design theme and running it on devices with lollipop version then the ripple effect will be used itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good library: [RippleView](https://github.com/siriscac/RippleView)

Hope it helps.

**Update**
The library above is only for `Buttons`, as I was pointed out.

This library, [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect), you can have the `Ripple Effect` to `Views` too.

Comment: Thanks, looks very nice.However, is it free OK to use it in commercial app? :)

Comment: There are Terms and Conditions here (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

Comment: Con: This is only for Buttons